# Orthographe de « blocage »

Tags: orthographe, étymologie

Pourquoi écrit-on « blocage » et pas « bloquage » ? Le sens me semble pourtant bien le même que celui de « bloquer ». Est-ce juste une question d'esthétique ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ce n'est pas une exception ; c'est un procédé assez courant pour les mots dont les noms communs de la même famille (je n'ai pas de définition rigoureuse) terminant par "c" :

"Truc" donne "truquer" *mais* "trucage"

"Floc" donne "floquer" *mais* "flocage" (floquer un maillot par exemple)

"Parc" donne "parquer" *mais* "parcage" (d'huîtres)

Je pense qu'il y en a de nombreux autres mais je n'ai pas la liste. Dans le cas de blocage, l'explication vient vraisemblablement du nom associé, un bloc.

Je ne pense pas que la règle soit systématique mais je n'ai pas de contre-exemple sous la main. Clac/claquer/claquage pourrait marcher mais je crois que claquage se réfère à la claque

Comment: C'est donc relativement esthétique. Merci pour les autres exemples auxquels je n'avais pas pensé !

Comment: @callisto Je ne sais pas si on peut parler d’esthétique… « Blocer » se prononcerait différemment, on emploie donc « bloquer ». Dans le cas de « blocage », ce n’est pas nécessaire.

Comment: *Claquage* (déchirure musculaire) vient bien de *claquer* et de *claque* coup donné avec le plat de la main (Le Robert - *claque* à d'autres signification qui ne se conjuguent pas) mais parmi les sens de *claquer* : se casser, éclater.

Comment: @cl-r donc peut-être que la règle est systématique. Je ne sais pas

Comment: @Édouard C'est vrai que "bloquage" n'est pas nécessaire. Logiquement "bloquer" vient de "bloc" et pas le contraire, donc les autres mots sur cette racine doivent dériver de "bloc" et gardent le 'c' sauf si nécessaire. Merci de tes remarques :)